# working with formattable() in Shiny renderDataTable()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to do some cell coloring on a table evaluating the value of some columns  using the formattable library :

APP code : 
    library(shiny)
    library(data.table)
    library(DT)
    library(formattable)

```
table <- fread("C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/Classeur2.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel(""),
   sidebarLayout(
      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput("Table")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$Table <-  renderDataTable({
     formattable(Table, list(
       S1 = formatter("span", 
                         style = ~ style(color = ifelse(x >= 0, "green",     
"red")))))
 })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There is x before ~ style

Comment: it was S1 sorry i forgot to change it before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I need to convert the table with as.datatable()